# Are programming questions whose context is strictly related to retro computers on topic?

Tags: discussion

The question " [Synchronising FOR - NEXT routines in C64 basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28406/synchronising-for-next-routines-in-c64-basic) " was closed as being *'off-topic. This question does not appear to be about retrocomputing.'*.

This question is asking how to do a specific thing in C64 BASIC. The body of the text is about manipulating the registers of the SID chip to produce multi-channel music within C64 BASIC.

Given this context, is this question, and other questions about programming a retrocomputer using the built-in, pack-in, bespoke or other standard programming languages, on-topic for Retrocomputing stack exchange?

What could guidelines be for conditions for a programming question to be on-topic?

Comment: It might be helpful to structure your opinion to the topic into an answer and confine the question to what you would like others to answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not certain how to use meta.

Comment: Works much like regular, just write your own answer as well, so people could gather under your PoV (aka voting for it) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that in general retroprogramming questions are very much on topic for the site.

But that question in particular seemed to be ignorant of the sequential nature of imperative programming. The discussion was of one loop needing to finish before starting the next sequential statement (another loop).  Well, yes.

That's not to sneer at beginners; we all (believe it or not, old people) were beginners at one point. It's just not really our subject here.

Answer (score 2):

I would see the question as dangling from the decision if BASIC as such is a retrocomputing topic. And I think it is. Even if there still are some remnants here and there (like VBA - which really cannot be considered BASIC to some extent - or retro-inspired small computers), BASIC has ceased to be part of the mainstream of programming languages at least since the millenium. You will likely not get any good answers on BASIC anywhere else on SE.

Answer (score 2):

As for the general question, my answer is yes, and I have in fact personally written [programming](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) [tag wiki description](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/programming/info) to that effect.

That said… the specific question which prompted this meta post is borderline at best.  If you squint, it asks about a solution to achieve a limited form of concurrency in an environment without any concurrency primitives like threads or coroutines.  But while the question was asked in the context of C64 BASIC, and this problem is probably more pressing on retro platforms, it’s still more of an algorithmic question than one about using a specific retro programming interface (like driving hardware registers, dealing with unusual memory addressing schemes or invoking syscalls on a retro platform).  One might as well imagine asking the same about a single-threaded multi-voice tracker program written in C for a contemporary OS, and the solution would have been largely the same: dovetailing.  I am not inherently opposed to reopening this question, but neither do I actively prefer it here.  (I also realize this approach would also exclude the situation which prompted the Foone tweet I am quoting in the tag wiki.  Oh well.)

I would be much more partial to reopening the [DirectX 8 question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24464/15334), which was closed for the usual, much more silly, gatekeeping reasons.

Comment: I think it's key to me that the answer would be written -in- C64 BASIC. An answer that wasn't wouldn't be enlightening. It might be correct in a hypothetical sense, but the question wasn't asked in a hypothetical sense. And, yes, please, let's reopen the linked q.

Comment: I am not sure I want to invite questions like “how do I add two numbers in C” merely because the asker wants to compile that C code for MS-DOS. This seems like that kind of question.

Comment: But what if the two numbers were being received by a serial port that had to be manually polled and the interrupts hooked maybe... :) Joking aside, adding two numbers would be a perfect minimal working example for a question about reading keyboard input in asm or making sure OpenWatcom or DJGPP was installed correctly or something. Adding numbers would be the goal, but the environment would be the difficulty.

Comment: But in the Stack Exchange Q&A format, you ask questions about difficulties, not about ultimate goals; the latter is a recipe for overly broad, unfocused questions. In a question about reading keyboard input or validating a compiler setup, the “adding two numbers” part would have been a dispensable detail, easily replaced with something else entirely or omitted altogether.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: Other BASIC questions may be a good fit, but not this one

I do not mind (generic) BASIC questions, or C64, but the question itself is not fit as one.

This particular question is not restricted in a meaningful manner to a retro context. A single mentioning of C64 as target in a secondary sentence does not create that context.  To make it on topic it would need to be essentially rewritten from scratch and that's what closing this one is about.

---

> This question is asking how to do a specific thing in C64 BASIC.

Well, that's exactly the problem I have with this specific question, as it does not contain **any** C64 specific information/question beside mentioning the machine itself. No detail that could create a C64 specific problem to be solved is mentioned.

Heck, it not even describes what it really does so far. **Only vague droppings - almost as if written by a KI.**

And that's the reason why I voted for closure (IIRC as 'needs more information'). I have written a few BASIC programs and some in other languages as well, but I can't really make any sense. That description is incredible unspecific, much like LLM generated Text.

- What should 'write to memory' mean?
- Feeding and calling some machine language routine, or poking into SID registers?
- Having FOR/NEXT running in parallel?
- Has he even understood the basic single process nature of (most old) BASICs?
- What is the date, since he complains about it being different for each voice?
- ... and so on.

Hard to find any sense or see hat program structure it features - at least not without making more assumptions than good for this.

> A possible answer may be applicable to BASICs in general,

BASIC as a language, especially with the constrictions of early MS BASIC is a special case. And while generic questions may be off-tpoic by the letters, I wouldn't mind to receive and answer them as part of he RC.SE context.

> For example, here the user wants to do multiple things at once, and if strict timing is required perhaps a C64 VBlank interrupt is the way to go - this possibility is an inherent part of the context of the question.

That sounds like you adding several assumption and going way off track for a answer to what seems to be asked. Not just because none of that is mentioned, but more as it's explicit stated that a BASIC only solution is intended.

The only thing I see from what is given would be an explanation how to pack three loops into one to get reach hard synchronisation. Of course that again is BASIC programming knowledge, neither BASIC or even less C64 specific.

Comment: You may have voted for closure for that reason, but the site is telling me the ultimate close reason was because it was off-topic.

Comment: AFAIK it records what the majority selected. Also [:))](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091203/quotes/?item=qt0337068&ref_=ext_shr_lnk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question is definitely on-topic. Programming a C64 using C64 BASIC is *the definition* of retrocomputing. Any suggestion to the contrary is nonsense.

The first line of the on-topic guidelines under 'What topics can I ask about here?' is:

> Questions are most welcomed on - how to use [...] computing equipment.

Programming questions relating to specific retrocomputing scenarios are a very good fit for RC:SE (and I've asked and answered several in the past to good effect). (Or even not-so-specific, but that's where I and received SE logic differ.)

If a question is specifically attempting to do something with a language that only makes sense in the context of a retro computer, it's on-topic. In this case, the question is about using C64 BASIC to manipulate SID registers in a suitable way to handle music timing correctly.

An answer *could* be general enough to describe how to handle the registers of a generic FM or PSG or wavetable sound generator, sure. The nature of hypothetical answers is irrelevant. The *question* is about doing it on the C64 in C64 BASIC. In fact, a generalised answer would be off-topic unless it also included an example of the advice requested about the C64 case specifically.

On the C64, the BASIC firmware is part of the computer as much as the keyboard, the user port or any other component. A question about some generic BASIC would be not automatically qualify regardless of the age of the BASIC used, but attempting to open a file requester in AmigaBASIC with Intuition for example would, to me, be obviously retrocomputing. There will of course be borderline scenarios where new hardware still supports old things: attempting to do I/O port access on a x86 system is still 'current' in the sense in that it's easy to buy a new graphics card and system combination that will work with the access, but VGA 13h programming and Mode X are certainly retrocomputing.

Comment: I'd agree to most of this (well, maybe not as enthusiastic about the 'definition'' thing:)), but **being on-topic** (going by the criteria your answer provides mentioning BASIC and C64 without concrete relation does not establish on-topicness) is **not he only criteria** to make a question acceptable for the site. Clearly describing the issue and doing most basic research is missing. Maybe more important here may be the way SE works: we have only a limited number of reasons to select and (as I understand) no real way to extend this. So selecting 'off topic' is often the default selction.

Comment: The topic was "Synchronizing FOR-NEXT loops".

Comment: Not the case dave. If the topic was -just- "Synchronizing FOR-NEXT loops", then there's a possibility someone could write an answer would be for DarkBASIC or BlitzBASIC or Visual BASIC, and the answer would be useless to the asker. The question was about C64 BASIC and with the extra context of manipulating the SID registers in real time. The distinction is important.